# mysql_query("INSERT INTO... is not working

Tags: php, mysql, registration, insert-into

I'm trying to create a registration page. The page is successfully connected to phpMyAdmin database but it does not echo anything when i click the register button.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<?php
INCLUDE "connect.php";
INCLUDE "functions.php";
INCLUDE "titlebar.php";
?>

            <div id="loginform">    
            <h1>Register</h1>

            <form name="Register" action="register.php" method="post">
            <?php
            if(isset($POST["submit"])){
                    $username = $_POST["username"];
                    $password = md5 ($_POST["password"]);
                    if(empty($username) or empty($password)){
                            echo "<p>Fields Empty!</p>";
                    } else {
                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO login VALUES('',$username','$password','2','')");
                            echo "<p>Successfully Registered!</p>";
                    }
            }
            ?>
                <p>     
                    <label for="username">Username: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></p><p>

                    <label for="password">Password: </label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></p><p>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
                </p>
            </form>
            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks you missed single quote `'` for variable `$username`. Anyway what error you are getting ..?

Comment: A lot wrong here. I suggest finding a good tutorial

Comment: The problem i am having is that when I press register, whether i have filled in the form or not, I am not getting any echo at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the post method.
use $_POST instead of $POST

Comment: this fixed the problem I was asking about, thank you. Now I am getting the correct echos showing but no entries are being shown in the database it is connected to... should i create a new question on stackoverflow or what

Comment: use '$username' instead $username'

Comment: I changed this but doesnt change anything.. any other ideas?

Comment: In the query you have added two fields after password, that is '2' and ' '.Can you please tell me the purpose of that. I didn't understand that.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/93e0bdca97c02c5440272bbd614ede88  these are the things in my database table. for "levels" it is either 1(admin) or 2(member). for "type" im not sure what this is for, i was following a tutorial but i ran into problems

Comment: just try 2 instead of '2'. that is remove the qoutes for integer value

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt change anything unfortunately

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO login VALUES('',$username','$password','2','normal')");

Comment: i think you fixed not null for type field and passing a null value. may be this will be the problem. And check whether the dbconnection is proper

Answer (score 0):

You have mysql error

Not: `$username'`

but `'$username'`

And next time display mysql errors with mysql_error().

Comment: thank you, I have changed this but it still does not fix the problem

Comment: So display finally this error what I told you: `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: after mysql_query(...) line

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, I am not sure what isset($_POST['submit'] should return, but as already mentioned in the comments you missed a single quote.

Additionaly i would use:

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'],
```

md5 is deprecated and thus not safe. If you write a login script you can use password_verify(plainPW, hashPW)

You also need to specify a database and login into it. I recommend to look at the W3 Schools examples they are very in-depth and have good examples.
[W3 school mysqli page](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp)

also write a die() at the end of your script and do not foregt to close the connection.